# Problem with Mic sound not coming through using UX1 interface

Tags: microphone, mac

sorry to have to ask but... need help please :)

1 x Shure Beta 87A mic... check...1 x UX1 interface with software installed... check...

trying to get mic feed right and not winning!!! Arrrggggg!!! Usb input into my Mac from UX1...POD Farm installed, mic in correctly to mic input on UX1, but still no mic signal coming through...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tamsin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 87A is a condenser and requires phantom power. UX1 does not provide phantom.

Comment: Wow. Whenever I hear the word Shure I think Dynamic. That's the problem right there. You need a Phantom Power adapter or a different mic...

Comment: mackatini don't forget to mark the answer as accepted answer when it uniquely solves your problem ;)